Apache ActiveMQ From C# switching queues
I have a process where I am consuming a message on a "status" queue.  I make connection to an ActiveMQ server, create a session, create a consumer to "status" with a JMSCorrelationID set, start the connection and receive a message.
Apache.NMS.IConnectionFactory factory = new Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory(url);
Apache.NMS.IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
                
sessionConsume = connection.CreateSession(Apache.NMS.AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);

Apache.NMS.IDestination sourceQueue = sessionConsume.GetQueue("status");
string filter = string.Format("JMSCorrelationID='{0}'", correlationID);
Apache.NMS.IMessageConsumer consumer = sessionConsume.CreateConsumer(sourceQueue,filter, true);

connection.Start();
Apache.NMS.ITextMessage message = consumer.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, ccMessageWait)) as Apache.NMS.ITextMessage;
if (message != null)
{
   //do something with the message
}

This works great.  When there is no message there, however, I want it to check a 2nd queue.   And here is where this gets unstuck.
if (message != null)
{
   //do somethign with the message
} else
{
   //Stop the current Connection, before opening again for OBQ
   //consumer.Close();
   //consumer.Dispose();
   //sourceQueue.Dispose();
   //connection.Stop();
   sourceQueue = sessionConsume.GetQueue("other");
   consumer = sessionConsume.CreateConsumer(sourceQueue, filter, true);
   connection.Start();
   message = consumer.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, ccMessageWait)) as Apache.NMS.ITextMessage;
   if (message != null)
   {
       ///ideally  there's a message here.....but alas.
   }   
}

I've tried creating whole new connections, new consumers, new queue object (IDestination). I've tried stopping connection, then starting connection, disposing consumers etc.
Basically I want to connect to status queue for that CorrelationID, and if nothing there, disconnect and connect to other queue.

What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

I don't understand what exactly the problem is. What exactly do you mean by, "here is where this gets unstuck"? Are you saying that when you try to receive a message from the "other" queue a message is not consumed even though a message is actually on the queue?

Any feedback here?
